# Android - Obtain Hidden Value in Web Form for POST

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup, okhttp

I've written a Login page in my App that has to connect to a site, to simulate the WebForm (from a Joomla site) in which is hidden a Token.

I need a way be able to extract that Token and then pass it as a Request in a Post using OKHTTP etc. I've used interceptors to follow the Login sequence etc and tried to do Parsing to no avail.

```
</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="2120448ca54231a666d6a0ee25d4b4e5" value="1" style="width: 250px; margin: 0px 25px;"></form>
```

The name part changes each time you land on the page and is passed along with the User ID & Password.

How could I get this using code, so I can then pass it into HTTP Request?

already spent 2 weeks now trying things and to work out how to capture some cookies that have to go back too only to find this hidden Token. (Learnt a lot along the way)

This has me beaten (at the moment), as I'm relatively new to Android programming.

Many Thanks for any support.

**Answer**

Started again from fresh and used JSOUP.Connect

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Element el = doc.select("input[type=\"hidden\"][value=\"1\"]").first();
hidden_token =  el.attr("name");
```

Now to use OKHTTP As the connector and pass to JSOUP Doc, as I think JSOUP.Connect will fetch another Token aside from the OKHTTP one.

Comment: this is most likely a `nonce`...which will change with every single request. starting two sessions with two cookies won't work; just fetch the form, get the `nonce` and then post the form; all with the same client, which has to present the session cookie to the server.

Comment: Thank you, I sorted it with Jsoup and also have a cookie that has to be returned.